Nicematrix not working version 6.28 2024-05-29
I'm using TeX Live 2019/Debian and I did the procedure accordingly https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix.
However get error nicematrix.sty:

erro: 35: Undefined control sequence. ...phase-table } \c_true_bool
\c_false_bool }. The error occurs in the file nicematrix.sty "
\IfPackageLoadedTF { latex-lab-testphase-table } \c_true_bool
\c_false_bool }"

\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{nicematrix}


\usepackage{tikz}  
    \begin{document}  
        $\begin{pNiceMatrix}  
        1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\  
        5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\\   
        9 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\\  
       \end{pNiceMatrix}   
    %  
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}[code-after = \tikz \draw (2-2) circle (2mm) ;]  
        1 & 2 & 3 \\\   
        4 & 5 & 6 \\\   
        7 & 8 & 9  
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$


\end{document}

I'm using the version 6.28 2024-05-29 nicematrix.  Does anyone know why this isn't working?

you mean you have a new nicematrix and try to use it in 2019 texlive? That won't work.

To explain it a little more: nicematrix is implemented using LaTeX3. The last L3 programming layer in TeX Live 2019 was <2020-02-25>. The nicematrix version 3.11 2020/02/07 would indeed work with this, but not nicematrix 6.28 2024-05-29. Maybe the L3 programming layer of your LaTeX installation is even older and you would need an even older version of nicematrix. All packages, that use L3 should usually be only updated altogether and with LaTeX resp. the L3 layer of LaTeX itself. See also my comment here.

Because it seems you are using debian texlive packages, you should remove your (manually?) installed nicematrix and instead use the texlive-… package of your debian installation, that provides nicematrix. AFAIK you need to apt install texlive-sience or apt install texlive-extra. But maybe best would be to install texlive-full. But I don't know, if that old version of nicematrix provides everything you need.

I uninstalled the version  TexLive 2019 and installed the version 2024  following the step https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html. This  worked for me. Thank you  all.
